# Android:How to sort list by date in android

Tags: android

I have a list view with many list items.Each list item contains testname,test enddate and no. of questions.I want to sort the list items according to dates.The dates which have expired are in grey color and new test dates are black. I am attaching the code which i have done till now.
can u please suggest me some code to do it.

```
  public class Test_List_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

public Activity context;
public String names[];
public String endDate[];
public String questions[];
public LayoutInflater inflater;

public Test_List_Adapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> testid,
        ArrayList<String> testName, ArrayList<String> endDate,
        ArrayList<String> questions) {
    this.context = context;
    this.names = testName.toArray(new String[0]);
    this.endDate = endDate.toArray(new String[0]);
    this.questions = questions.toArray(new String[0]);
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return names.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView testname;
    TextView questions;
    TextView testenddate;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    try {

        ViewHolder holder;
        ViewHolder holder1 = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            //inflater = (LayoutInflater)               context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
              //                inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_list_items,
                    null);
            holder.testname = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.testName);
            holder.questions = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.noofQuestions);
            holder.testenddate = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.testDate);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        final long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.d("Current date", date + "");
        long endtime = Constants.test_closetime.get(position);
        endtime = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(endtime);
        Log.v("end time of selected class is: ", endtime + "");


        if (date < endtime) {
            Log.d("color", "white");
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            holder.testenddate.setText(endDate[position]);



        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("color", "gray");
            holder.testenddate.setText(endDate[position]);
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);


        }

        /*for (int i = 0; i < Constants.test_closetime.size(); i++) 
        {
            long endtime1 = Constants.test_closetime.get(i);
            endtime1 = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(endtime1);
            for (int j = i+1; j < Constants.test_closetime.size(); j++)
            {
                long endtime2 = Constants.test_closetime.get(j);
                endtime2 = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(endtime2);
                if(endtime1<endtime2)
                {
                    long temp;
                    temp=endtime1;
                    endtime1=endtime2;
                    endtime2=temp;
                                                                                                        holder.testenddate.setText(endDate[position]);
                }

            }
            holder.testenddate.setText(endDate[position]);
        }*/     


        holder.testenddate.setText(endDate[position]);
        holder.testname.setText(names[position]);
        holder.testenddate.setText(endDate[position]);
        holder.questions.setText(questions[position]);
        Log.v("exiting =test list adapter", "true");






            Log.v("exiting =test list adapter", "return convertview");
             } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Test_List_Adapter/getView()", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
         }
              return convertView;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Do you get any error or simply above code does not work?

Comment: I didnt got errors.the code works fine but i dont know how to sort the list

Answer (score 1):

- Create a container class for one list item that contains name, endDate and question.
- Instead of having three string arrays, have one ArrayList that contains those containers.
- Sort that ArrayList using Collections.sort(List, Comparator)

Let us know if you need specific help with any of those steps.

Extra credit:

- Use a Date object instead of a string to represent dates.